# Enable proxy support of pyLast

Tags: python, last.fm

I want to enable the proxy, I found a method named `enable_proxy`, but when I do it like this:

```
network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY, api_secret = API_SECRET, username = username, password_hash = password_hash)

network.enable_proxy("http//...", 8080)
```

I get a network error: `[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`, because the call of `pylast.LastFMNetwork` tries to generate a network session key. How can I enable the proxy support of pylast? I don't find any example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to scrobble, you can create a network object without the session key by omitting a username/password hash, like here:

- https://github.com/ticklemynausea/mbot-shell/blob/199d65c5841cb7e0f9f2cc5aec677bcb45ffe5b4/lastfm/lastfm.py#L34
- https://github.com/devilcius/last2what/blob/8d6b0a87dc25a859c137670fee67643c99e0c78d/last2what.py#L103

Like this:

```
network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key, api_secret)
if proxy_enabled:
    network.enable_proxy(host = proxy_host, port = proxy_port)
```

Do you need to scrobble? If so, try something like this after enabling the proxy:

```
network.username = my_username
network.password_hash = my_password_hash
sk_gen = SessionKeyGenerator(network)
network.session_key = sk_gen.get_session_key(my_username, my_password_hash)
```

Note: `httplib.HTTPConnection` doesn't support authentication, so if you don't have to authenticate yourself, the second one should work (with the latest GitHub version of pylast; there's a bug fix not yet released).

See also: https://github.com/pylast/pylast/issues/103